# Decimal to binary conversion in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, division

I am trying to display binary representation of a decimal in MIPS. but this program is stuck in infinite loop. I couldn't figure out the problem so please tell me what am I doing wrong and is this program valid for finding binary represenatation of a number. Here is the code:

```
Loop:

div $s0,$t1   # t1 is 2

mflo $s0      # storing quotient in s0 for division
mfhi $s4

move $a0,$s4
li $v0,1
syscall

beq $s4,0,Exit

j Loop
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$s4` is the current digit (the remainder). You should be testing `$s0` for zero. This should have been obvious if you stepped through the code in a debugger/simulator. Also note this will print the digits in reverse order.

If you only need binary conversion, the usual way is to just use shifts.

Answer (score 0):

Branching in assembly comes with its hazards. Usually you would stall you program until the branch is taken. This is done in order to prevent the program from executing next instruction in the instruction set.

In your case I would try placing a `noop` after `beq` instruction.
`SLL $0, $0, 0`

`noop` is an instruction which doesn't have any effect on the program or has no meanning.